# How can I get only method name that return true

Tags: ruby

As I written in title, How can I get method name that return true.

```rb
def foo
 true 
end 

def bar 
 false
end 

def baz 
 false 
end 

arr = [foo, bar, baz]
# above return [true, false, false]
# My teribble way 
%w(foo bar baz).zip(arr).select{|a, b| b}
# => [["foo", true]]
```

I want to know that is method name. In the above case is foo.
Any better idea?

Comment: Should it be an array of method names that return `true` or there is only one such method and you want to get its name?

Comment: It would be great if you post the output that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
p %w(foo bar baz).filter_map { |method_name| method_name if send(method_name) }
```

Output

```
["foo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
%w(foo bar baz).select { |name| send(name) }
#=> ["foo"]
```

Or even shorter:

```
%w(foo bar baz).select(&method(:send))
#=> ["foo"]
```